# Error creating a column: replacement has 0 rows, data has 1

Tags: r, function, subset

I'm trying to create a function to organize my data.I need to create new columns, to classify the sample (i.e. each row) as 'overlap', 'non_over' or 'lower'. However, when it read the column creation code, I receive the following:

```
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "overlap", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1"
```

Follows my code:

```
org <-function(bpoint){
bp <- data.frame(bpoint)
colnames(bp)<-gsub(x=colnames(bp)," ","_")
colnames(bp)<-gsub(x=colnames(bp),"(","",fixed=T)
colnames(bp)<-gsub(x=colnames(bp),")","",fixed=T)

bp$overlap <- (bp$"Low_Freq_Hz"<=2000&bp$"High_Freq_Hz">2000)
bp$non_over <- (bp$"Low_Freq_Hz">2000)
bp$lower <- (bp$"High_Freq_Hz"<=2000)
bp$time <- 'before'
}
```

I assume this must be an fool mistake, but I can't find any helpful solutions in other related questions... Why can't I create this columns and how can I solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Remove the quotes from your column names `bp$Low_Freq_Hz` etc - assuming that these are actual variable names.

Comment: What @AndrewGustar said and also your function returns nothing. If you want it to return `bp` include its name as the last instruction. You can either do `return(bp)` or simply `bp`.

Comment: the quotes are unnecessary but won't make it crash

Comment: use `debugonce` and check the values line by line, you'll probably figure the issue yourself and if not you'll have more info for us

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. Besides the quotes, I also removed the creation of the data frame on 2nd line, and stated only bp <- bpoint. Can't figure the reason of these errors, but looks like working now!

Comment: possibly a typo in the column names ?

Comment: No, column names are fine except for the quotes...

Comment: When doing return(bp) I only receive the output of the function, but do not save as an object, is there a specific way to do it?